# Search for partial strings

Tags: apostrophe-cms

Is there a setting (or snippet) I can use to perform searches for partial string matches using apostrophe-search? For example: a search for "blue" should return the item with the title "Learning Management Blueprint".

Comment: In my test, searching for partial string of "blue" works:
 var cursor = self.apos.docs.find(req,
                {
                    lowSearchText:  /blue/
                }
            )

but making this a variable doesn't. Shouldn't this be equivalent and work?

var searchText =  'blue';
var cursor = self.apos.docs.find(req,
                {
                    lowSearchText: searchText
                }
            )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know I am the lead developer of Apostrophe at P'unk Avenue.

Your solution does work, however one serious concern with it is that you are not escaping the user's input to prevent regular expression meta-characters like `.` and `*` from being interpreted as such. For that you can use `apos.utils.regExpQuote(s)`, which returns the string with the dangerous characters escaped via `\`.

There is a better way to do this though: just use `req.query.autocomplete` instead. Apostrophe has a built-in `autocomplete` cursor filter that works differently from the `search` filter. The `autocomplete` filter allows partial matches (although only at the start of a word) and then it feeds the words it finds through the regular `search` so that results are still sorted by match quality. It also maintains much of the performance benefit of using `search`.

A regular expression search like yours will scan the entire mongodb collection (well, at least all docs of the relevant type), which means you'll have performance problems if you have a lot of content.

One caveat with `autocomplete` is that it only "sees" words in high-priority fields like title, tags, etc. It does not see the full text of a doc the way your regex search (or the `search` filter) can. This was a necessary tradeoff to keep the performance up.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding a RegExp is what is needed. In case anyone else needs this, here is the relevant lib\modules\apostrophe-search\index.js code:

```
module.exports = {
  perPage: 15,
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.indexPage = function(req, callback) {

        req.query.search = req.query.search || req.query.q;
        var allowedTypes;

        var defaultingToAll = false;
        var cursor = self.apos.docs.find(req, { lowSearchText: new RegExp(req.query.search, 'i') } )
            .perPage(self.perPage);
            if (self.filters) {
            var filterTypes = _.filter(
                _.pluck(self.filters, 'name'),
                function(name) {
                    return name !== '__else';
                }
            );
```